# ircd on aws ssl error

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services

I have unrealirc running on my aws and it is compiled with ssl. I downloaded the server.key.pem to my machine. When I try to connect to the server I get`SSL Error: ssl not available`
 I can log into aws through a terminal with my server key.

```
02[10:48] * Connecting to ec2-xx-xx-xx-114.compute-1.amazonaws.com (+6697)
-
02[10:48] * SSL error: ssl not available
-
02[10:48] * Connect cancelled
```

Also I added the correct port to my Security Group
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the openssl shared libraries on your ec2 instance? That seems unlikely but without more info seems most likely from the error.

On a Redhat based image try:

```
yum search ssl
```

and Debian try

```
apt-cache search ssl
```

That will tell you what ssl libraries are installed.